# Converting EditorTemplate into HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I originally created an editor template like this

```
@model MyModel
var items = // get items
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, items, new { id = Html.IdFor(m => m) })
```

which was invoked by

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeClass)
```

where `SomeClass` has an `Id` property. (The `IdFor` is one of my HTML helpers).

This would generate something like this

```
<select name="SomeClass.Id" id="SomeClass" />
```

Now I want to change the editor template into an HTML helper, so that my call looks like this

```
@Html.CustomEditorFor(m => m.SomeClass)
```

I'm changing this from a view to helper because its easier for reusability.

This is loosely what I have:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var idString = htmlHelper.IdFor(expression);
    var propertyValue = expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
    var items = // get items
    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items, new {id = idString});
}
```

However, when I call the editor, I get this HTML instead of what I want.

```
<select name="SomeClass" id="SomeClass" />
```

How can I modify the expression enough to allow it to "access" the `Id` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var idString = htmlHelper.IdFor(expression);
    var items = // get items

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "m");
    var member = Expression.Property(
                     Expression.Property(param, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression))
                 , "Id");

    var isNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(member.Type);
    if (isNullable != null) {
        var expr2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, int?>>(
                        member, new[] { param }
                    );

        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expr2, items, new { id = idString });
    }

    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, int>>(
                   member, new[] { param }
               );

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expr, items, new { id = idString });
}
```

Comment: is `new[] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "m") }` dependent on what i've passed before? it might not always be `m`.

Comment: i do constrain `TProperty` to an interface so it does have it.

Comment: what should i do for when the Id property can either be `int` or `int?`? i get "Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'" when i use `int?`.

Comment: please see if the modified code works.. couldn't get simpler.